# how to check same Object Name across databases on the same server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to find duplicate object name across all databases on one server. Is there away to find all duplicate? I am using cursor to loop through the databases and I want to check if an object shows more than one and column called duplicates will be populated with Yes or No.

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Answer (score 2):

use the msforeachdb builtin function/proc, then insert those results into a temp table. Then query the temp table and do a groupby having count(1) > 1

```
create table #tables (db varchar(100) not null, name varchar(100) not null)
exec sp_msforeachdb 'use [?] insert into #tables select distinct db_name(), [name] from sys.objects where [type] = ''U'''
select name, count(1) from #tables group by name having count(1) > 1 order by 2 desc
drop table #tables
```

This isn't exact, but you get the idea. I'll keep tweaking until I know it's right.

Here's the cursor version:

```
set nocount on

SELECT name
into #dbs
FROM sys.databases

declare dbCursor cursor local forward_only for
select name from #dbs

declare @db varchar(100)

create table #tables (db varchar(100) not null, name varchar(100) not null)

open dbCursor
fetch next from dbCursor into @db

while (@@fetch_status = 0) begin
    begin try
    exec ('use ' + @db + ' insert into #tables select distinct db_name(), [name] from sys.objects where [type] = ''U''')
    print 'got ' + @@rowcount + ' from db ' + @db
    end try
    begin catch
        print 'couldn''t retrieve data from database ' + @db
    end catch
    fetch next from dbCursor into @db
end

close dbCursor
deallocate dbCursor

select name, count(1) from #tables group by name having count(1) > 1 order by 2 desc
drop table #tables
drop table #dbs
```

Comment: This is only getting the result from 1 database

Comment: That is the problem. I can not use msforeachdb since it is not documented by microsoft

Comment: @zeze is this a test question by chance?

Comment: Lol no I am doing some data analysis on one of my local servers

Comment: If you can't use sp_msforeachdb, then use your cursor to iterate over all of the databases, then use dynamic sql to replace the '?' above.

Comment: @ganders in your first example you are grouping by database, is that intentional ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk no, thanks for catching that. It's fixed.

Comment: make sure to accept if this fixed your [coding] issue :)